# How can I find the specific ports and protocols being used by my ECS Fargate Services on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

We have a single VPC in our AWS account. This single VPC contains a number of ECS Fargate Services. The VPC network ACL allows all protocols and all ports from all ips. As a security best practise, we want to restrict the ports and protocols that are being allowed.

Is there a way to find the ports and protocols currently open or being used by the ECS Fargate Services, so that we could specifically open only those ports and protocols in the NACL?

We don't want an all traffic all port rule in the VPC NACL.

We tried to find the IP ranges which the AWS uses to assign IP addresses to ECS services and put those IP ranges in the NACL. But whenever, we removed the all traffic all port rule, the traffic to ECS services was stopped. We couldn't find a way to narrow down on the exact IP addresses or ports to allow in the NACL.

Answer (score 0):

You should examine the [ECS task definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html). All the ports will be defined there. ECS/Fargate will only expose ports that are explicitly defined in the task definition, so you can be sure to find them all there.